# Problems with Java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, split

I cannot seem to get the text that I want using regex.

I need the text separated with "...from...to..."

Sample input:

```
text1 from text2 to text3
```

My current code:

```java
String[] word=input.split("from|to",3);

System.out.println("Text 1: "+word[0]);
System.out.println("Text 2: "+word[1]);
System.out.println("Text 3: "+word[2]);
```

Any ideas how I can improve this code if, for example, I want to ignore  the word '..from..to..' in Text1 and only use the '...from..to..', which is in the last occurrence (i.e. text2 and text3)

Example:

```
from here to China will take you from 10 to 12 hours.
```

I want the text:

- text1: `from here to China will take you` as one single sentence
- text2: `10`
- text3: `12 hours`

Comment: So what's the problem? Be more specific than "I'm stuck".

Comment: maybe try add this line before: input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing code, which is on topic at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg If this code is not working (“*I cannot seem to get the text that I want*”), then it is *not* on-topic for code review! Should it later become clear that this code is in fact working as intended, you could flag it for migration.

Comment: @amon Sorry, the question has been edited. Indeed correct that this question is **not** on-topic for CR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will split your phrase like in your example:

```
String input = "from here to China will take you from 10 to 12 hours";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split("\\bfrom\\b\\s+(?=\\d)|\\bto\\b\\s+(?=\\d)")));
```

The problem with simply using `from|to` in the split method was that your phrase contained multiple occurences of `from` and `to`. So in this case was necessary to specify that you want only the `from` and `to` that is followed by spaces and a digit. Also added word-boundary `\\b` to match only `to` word and not words containing `to` like for example `toronto`

---

so you could adjust your code like this:

```
String[] word=input.split("\\bfrom\\b\\s+(?=\\d)|\\bto\\b\\s+(?=\\d)");

System.out.println("Text 1: "+word[0]);

System.out.println("Text 2: "+word[1]);

System.out.println("Text 3: "+word[2]);
```

**Update**: The regex could be actually simplyfied to:

```
\\b(from|to)\\b\\s+(?=\\d)
```

Answer (score 1):

String split() will not help you in this purpose. You have to use pattern matching. See this example:

```
String text = "from here to China will take you from 10 to 12 hours";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(from\\s+.*?)\\s+from\\s+(\\d+)\\s+to\\s+(\\d+\\s+hours?)\\b");

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

This will not work if your string's format change in anything else.